# Auth::check() return false Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication

I am facing an issue with Auth, I have admin middleware and handle function inside, but `Auth::check` always return false. Seems like user session doesn't exist.

I thought the problem was in permissions for `/storage` and `/bootstrap/cache`, but when I set up `777` for these folders the problem still the same. Session folder is not empty.

I have tried to clear cache.

My Admin Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //check the proper role
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else {
        return response()->view('auth.forbidden')->header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using your own authentication system or Laravel's one ?

Comment: Custom Laravel Auth, I just added my Admin middleware. On the local server, everything works well. This problem only on the production server.

Comment: @zm_fans Please display your middleware details

Comment: Can you please place your route code?

Comment: Route::auth(); , all routes under "web" middleware group. And Admin routes have 'admin' middleware.
<code>Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'web'), function() {
    Route::get('/',[
        'uses' => 'Back\AdminController@index',
        'as' => 'admin.index',
        'middleware' => 'admin'
    ]);
});</code>

Comment: Ok, check the accepted answer from this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841031/laravel-basic-http-auth-check-returning-false). Hope this is your solution.

Comment: I have already checked this answer, all my routes under "web" middleware and my Kernel.php looks the same.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use something like

```
//check the proper role
    $user = $request->user();
    if ($user && $user->isAdmin()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else {
        return response()->view('auth.forbidden')->header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    }
```

will work is user is logged in  and isAdmin